# Is there a regular bipartite graph where the minimum cuts are trivial?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

My question is: Given integers $r$ and $k$, is there an $r$-regular bipartite graph $G = L \cup R$ with $|L| = |R| = k$, which is $r$-edge connected, and such that every minimum cut is trivial?

I can make an $r$-regular $r$-edge connected bipartite graph $G = L \cup R$ with $|L| = |R| = k$, by taking a union of some hamiltonian cycles, but it has many non-trivial minimum cuts. (I say a cut is trivial if it is the set of edges incident on a single vertex).

If $r = 2$, then I think the only $r$-regular connected bipartite is a hamiltonian cycle, so it does not hold. Can it ever hold? In general how can I ensure that the minimum cuts are trivial in a graph?

Comment: I'm not sure why you say this does hold if $r=2$? A cycle of length at least 4 has plenty of non-trivial 2-edge cuts. Not a full answer, but this can hold for $r=k$, I don't think the complete bipartite graphs $K_{r,r}$ can have any non-trivial cuts with $r$ edges.

Comment: Well, I don't know if this question has the short and snappy answer you are looking for, but to answer your question, *most* $r$-regular graphs have this property, and not only that, but they also satisfy a much stronger property; every set $S$ has $cr|S|$ edges with exactly one endpoint outside of $S$ for any $S$ that is not more than half the vertices.  The explicit Ramanujan graphs satisfy this. As far as *checking* whether or not your graph has the property you desire, I'm not sure of a nice elementary way to do so though.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez Thank you, that was a typo.

Comment: @Mike I am not following your comment. Do they have _at least_ $cr|S|$ edges in $\delta(S)$ or exactly this many? Can I choose the constant $c$?